# ¿Como concatenar un valor para ingresar el mismo en un update?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta, estoy tratando de concatenarle a este update

```
update tdato set valor= (select max(valor)+1 from tdato)
```

el valor que me retorna mas un texto, intente tratando de contatenarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
update tdato set valor = ('AG-')+convert(varchar,(select max(valor)+1 from tdato))
```

Pero no me ha funcionado y en documentación no encuentro algo útil.

De ante mano agradeciendo sus aportes.

Comment: que error tira esa query?? valor es de tipo varchar o algo asi?

Comment: @gbianchi El error esta despues de concatenar ya no puedo seguir usando el query porque el select max ya no devuelve un int si no un varchar ese es el error que me arroja

Comment: y es correcto. deberis obtener la parte que es solo numerica para poderle sumar uno. el texto de adelante es siempre igual?

Comment: @gbianchi si siempre es igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de la siguiente manera:

```
update tdato set valor = (select 'AG-' + Convert(Varchar, max(SUBSTRING(valor, CHARINDEX('-', valor, 1) + 1, len(valor) - CHARINDEX('-', valor, 1))) + 1) from tdato)
```

Primero obtienes del campo valor de tu tabla, el texto que este después de "AG-" que puede ser, 1, 2, 3, etc, (ya que mencionas que se almacena como AG-1, AG-2, AG-3, AG-n), a ese valor le sumas 1 y luego le concatenas de nuevo el texto AG-.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono a la perfección.

Comment: @BrianVelez de nada, que bueno que te haya servido.